# Make a custom UIView perform the Speak action

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6, speech

In most Apple-provided controls, you can tap and hold on the text, and get the copy/paste menu, which usually has "Speak" at the end.

I have a custom control (UIView descendant) I want to do the same with.

I can pop up my own menu no problem, and while I dont need them, copy and paste are built in, but is there any (appstore legal) way to make the control "speak" on the users command, given a block of text?

I don't want to trigger it in code without user interaction. Well, I do, but I suspect thats going to be impossible, or there would be lots of code/docs around to do it :)

VoiceOver is not an option, as the app is targeted at kids, and the change in gestures with voiceover is likely to cause problems. I already have the accessability properties set with the appropriate data, so if it *is* on, then that works.

Thanks!

Comment: wow, stumped even StackOverflow...

Comment: Also, [aparantly](http://9to5mac.com/2013/06/27/new-for-app-developers-in-ios-7-text-to-speech-motion-effects-background-downloads-free-in-app-purchases-more/) this is in a "future release of iOS". In theory.